# How to delete duplicate countries in data frame but keep entry in most recent year (R)?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a data frame with many countries, an example like so:

```
country year
USA     2018
USA     2017
UK      2015
UK      2013
```

I want to amend the data frame so that the country only appears once, specifically the one with the most recent year. I.e. I want:

```
country year
USA     2018
UK      2015
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can group by 'country' and use `slice_max` to return the max 'year' for each 'country'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   slice_max(year)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   country [2]
#  country  year
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 UK       2015
#2 USA      2018
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "UK", "UK"), year = c(2018L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2013L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
res <- df %>% arrange(country,desc(year)) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(country))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   country [2]
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 UK       2015
2 USA      2018
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "UK", "UK"), year = c(2018L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2013L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```